# Compare dates in DataView.RowFilter?

Tags: c#, datetime, dataview, date-format, rowfilter

I am scratching my head over something rather stupid yet apparently difficult.

```
DataView dvFormula = dsFormula.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dvFormula.RowFilter = "'" + startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' < EndDate OR EndDate = '19000101'";
dvFormula.Sort = "FromDate ASC";
```

The result is this:

> Cannot perform '<' operation on System.String and System.DateTime.

Please tell me what the best way to solve this problem would be.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to wrap your dates with #, not apostrophes.

```
dvFormula.RowFilter = "#" + startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# < EndDate OR EndDate = #1/1/1900#";
```

Comment: You're right it was the #. But the crucial part is that the dateformat needs to be the same as the one your system settings are using. How stupid is that... so now I'm using `startDate.ToShortDateString()`. Thanks m8!

Comment: Didn't know about the date format matching system settings.  Thanks for educating me and anyone else who reads this!

Comment: @Peter, here in the UK (where our date format makes sense - dd/mm/yyyy) I have to use EITHER "yyyy/MM/dd" or the American layout. If I do ToShortDateString then it has a flip-out. In addition, I recommend the "yyyy/MM/dd" format as it is not a locale specific format - unless anybody has better info?

Comment: In T-SQL I'm used to the `yyyyMMdd` format but with rowfilter `yyyy/MM/dd` looks like the way to go then? Thanks, very helpfull.

Answer (score 12):

This is the solution. Try this:

```
filter = " (Date >= #" +
         Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") +
         "# And Date <= #" +
         Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") +
         "# ) ";
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your data provider, you may need to escape dates with the `#` character rather than the `'` character. In addition, I would format your dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` to ensure it can be recognized as a date correctly.