# Converting DateTime to format of "MMM dd, yyyy" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, dataview, rowfilter

I have DateTime object Edate with value in format of "MM-dd-yyyy" like "01-10-2014" , but i need to use Rowfilter on my Dataview on a Date column which has value in format of "MMM dd,yyyy" like "Jan 10,2014" .
I am not able to use Rowfilter because of the format .
How can i solve this issue and filter on Date column with format in "MMM dd,yyyy" .

The value is coming from SQLSERVER in which Date column has format of 107 sql datetime format.

Comment: can we get some code? Did you already tried something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584571/compare-dates-in-dataview-rowfilter - also, use `#yyyy/MM/dd#` for RowFilter, not whatever odd "MMM dd, yyyy" format. Alternatively, just use LINQ instead of RowFilter expressions. (RowFilter is *not* TSQL or SQL Server so the SQL Server / 107 format doesn't matter - see these [RowFilter syntax examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).)

Answer (score 3):

Demo for you:

```
var thisDate1 = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") + ".");
```

This link you help: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To change the format, you can use `toString()` method:

Ex:

```
dateObj.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Relax said above; seeing some code would help.

In the meantime, if you are sure the format comes in this format `MM-dd-yyyy`, you can split it as a string with `('-')` to get the individual `day`, `month` and `year` object so you can create a new date instance from the objects with your defined format.

The date function relies on your system culture settings and this determine the expected data format. If you are on `Framework 4.5`, you can set Global Culture UI in your `web.config` or `app.config` for the entire project