# How to display the current month records from Access database in a datagridview on form load in vb.net

Tags: .net, ms-access, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I can display all records with this code below but I would only like to see the current month records, or at very least the last 31 days

```
Public Sub Display_Data()

 con.Open() 'opening the connection

 Dim dt As New DataTable("tbLMPH")
 Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbLMPH", con)
 rs.Fill(dt)
 DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
 DataGridView1.Refresh()

 Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count

 rs.Dispose()

 con.Close()

 End Sub
```

Comment: What do you think would work?  How would you go about doing this?

Comment: I know inserting a where clause in the select statement should work. I have tried ("Select * from tbLMPH where Year(datadate) = year(getdate()) and month(datadate) = month(getdate())", con)  I later found that this is a MySQL statement and need a access equivalent.                                                                                                     I forgot to write i'm a newbie to coding.

Comment: What is the datatype of *tbLMPH.datadate*, Date/Time or text?

Comment: I tried date/time but that just confused me even more. I believe I have the date columns split into 3 column 1 IDThisDay, ThisMonth & This Year

Comment: What are the datatypes of your *ThisMonth* and *This Year* fields ... numeric or text?  Does *This Year* hold 2-digit or 4-digit year values?

Comment: I tried date/time but that just confused me even more. I believe I have the date columns split into 3 text columns. column 1 (KEY)= ID - column 2 =ThisDay, column 3 =ThisMonth & column 4 =This Year. So I need the information from column 3(month) & 4(Year) to be the focus on form load. I can remake my DB if I need the date/time function.

Comment: HansUp, I'm pretty sure they are txt format. Oh and this year hold 4 digits i.e. 2015

Comment: What is the deal here, Jason?  Can't you just open the database in Access and check the fields' definitions in Design View for that table?

Comment: sorry mate I'm actually at work lol. I am certain they are in Text format as I originally had date/time format so changed it back to text. I can modify any way you need me to to make this work.

Comment: I suggest you create and test a query in the Access query designer.  Access SQL includes a `Date()` function which returns the current date as an Access Date/Time value; it does not support a `getdate()` function.

Comment: Ok, I understand what your saying but I have no idea how to implement this.  Sorry for the lack of my coding knowledge. I have only been involved in coding for about 4 weeks and I am still on a very steep learning curve, thats why im asking for any help I can.

Comment: I have re-read your comment. I am trying to import the current month data into datagridview. I don't understand why I'd have to query Access DB to view all the records for the current month when viewing in the grid. I wanted to see if there is a way only to load those details at form load. I can query Access to show todays date but I want to show all records that have already been entered,

Comment: Hi HansUp, I think I got it.                                                                        Year([ThisDate])=Year(Now()) And Month([ThisDate])=Month(Now())                                                                                                                Now that I created the query in access does this mean I should use the query to fill the datagrid or can the code now be put into the select statement in my supplied code? I'm still confused but please be patient with me. yes I am silly lol.

Answer (score 0):

First, do change back the field to data type Date. Dates should always be handled like dates, not strings, no exceptions.

Second, you can use a DataView to control the filtering as described here:

[How to filter DataGridView in VB.NET](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_sort.htm)

Your filter should be `>= MonthFirst and <= MonthLast`, and these can be found this way:

```
Dim Today As DateTime = DateTime.Today
Dim MonthFirst = new DateTime(Today.Year, Today.Month, 1)
Dim MonthLast = MonthFirst.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: So sorry, but I have another question. Where is this example code entered? Is it placed into the display data function or is this a query for query builder? Please bare with me as I am totally new and feel embarrassed. This is a very steep learning curve. I need to figure it out for myself but a hint would be great.

Comment: I would say you should just expand your current code and introduce a DataView as demonstrated in the link. So it is not a copy-paste but an adjustment of your code.

Comment: Public Sub Display_Data()

             con.Open() 'opening the connection
             
             Dim dt As New DataTable("tblarp")
             Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblarp", con)
             Dim Today As DateTime = DateTime.Today
             Dim MonthFirst = New DateTime(Today.Year, Today.Month, 1)
            Dim MonthLast = MonthFirst.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
            rs.Fill(dt)
      DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        
        Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count

        rs.Dispose()

        con.Close()




    End Sub

Comment: Nothing happens? Data is displayed but not filtered.

Comment: You have only specified MonthFirst and MonthLast. You will need to create and use a filtered DataView as the article explains.

Comment: Public Class Form1
Public Sub Display_Data()
con.Open() 'opening the connection
Dim dt As New DataTable("tblarp")
Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblarp", con)
Dim dv As DataView
dv = New DataView(ds.Tables(0), "ThisDay = '>= MonthFirst' ", "<= MonthLast", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
Dim Today As DateTime = DateTime.Today
Dim MonthFirst = New DateTime(Today.Year, Today.Month, 1)
Dim MonthLast = MonthFirst.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)rs.Fill(dt)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
DataGridView1.Refresh()
   Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Countrs.Dispose()

Comment: You probably need to have the first and last dates as properly formatted string expression: `#2015-07-04#` ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584571/compare-dates-in-dataview-rowfilter)